# 2D Collision, how to transfer forces?

Tags: java, android, collections, physics

I've got 3 main elements at work here.
Momentum, Mass, and Momentum rotation.

Mass is worked out by:

```
this.mMass = (this.getHeight() + this.getWidth()) / 2.0f;
```

I've created a system that automatically creates polygons around transparent pngs and detects collision perfectly (with high performance) but now I'm stuck on how to apply forces when they collide.

I'm using LibsGDX but theres nothing about how to detect collisions using polygons and how to deal with them anywhere (manually without using their world)

Only needs to be basic collision forces, when I look online everything seems to be way too complicated!

What I have so far..

```
//Collision detection - loop though all physical objects.
    for(PhysicalObject physicalObject1 : AllPhysicalObjects)
    {
        for(PhysicalObject physicalObject2 : AllPhysicalObjects)
        {
            //Check that it's no trying to collide with it-self.
            if(physicalObject1 != physicalObject2 && physicalObject1.mIsCurrentlyPhysical)
            {
                if(Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(physicalObject2.mPolygon, physicalObject1.mPolygon))
                {
                    //Functions.out("Class:" + eachPhysicalObject.getClass().toString());
                    //Now the fucking collision detection...
                    //Gonna be hard, but worth it when done right.

                    //Get the amount of momentum from the first physical object.
                    float physicalObject1Momentum = physicalObject1.mMomentum - physicalObject2.mMass;
                    float physicalObject2Momentum = physicalObject2.mMomentum - physicalObject2.mMass;

                    //If the momentum is negative, reverse the direction the object is going in.
                    if(physicalObject1Momentum < 0.0f)
                    {
                        //Reverse the direction of object1.
                        physicalObject1.setMomentumRotationRotation(Functions.getRotationalMaxMinStatic(180f, physicalObject1.getMomentumRotation()));
                        //Decrease the momentum of object2.


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Slow down the physical objects 1 momentum.
                        physicalObject1.increaseMomentum(-physicalObject1Momentum);

                        physicalObject2.increaseMomentum(physicalObject1.mMaxMomentum);
                        physicalObject2.setMomentumRotationRotation(Functions.getRotationalMaxMinStatic(180f, physicalObject1.getMomentumRotation()));
                    }



                    //Compare both momentums.



                    //Compare mass.

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Way too complicated?  How so?  Detecting collisions is not trivial...the physics are what they are.

Comment: Why don't you just use JBox2D, which is a part of libGDX?

Comment: And how would one go about that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision has the "final speeds". With this you can react to all the collisions that happen on the line that connects the centers of mass of the two objects. ...I'am sorry to tell you that more than this IS "way more complicated". Collisions are REALLY hard...